# PHP - Capture All POST Variables

Tags: php, post, get

Is there a way in PHP to capture all post and get variables that are sent to a page?

I am testing my PayPal Subscription website in the PayPal Sandbox but every transaction I do triggers the invalid transaction in my code.

So, I would like to capture everything that PayPal sends to my ipn page and see if I can make sense of what is going on. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a PayPal IPN, you should be able to use `$postdata = file_get_contents('php://input');` to fetch the raw post data needed for the validation callback.

Comment: this looks like a simple method, is there a special handler to register to get this to work?

Comment: @TerryKernan: No, no special handler. But note that it doesn't work for Content-Type: multipart/form-data. See http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php for details.

Answer (score 4):

I've got a simple method that helps me capture all the post data:

```
$post_vars = "";
if ($_POST) {
    $kv = array();
    foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) {
        if (is_array($v)):
            $temp = array();
            foreach ($v as $v2) {
                $temp[] = $v2;
            }
            $kv[] = "$k=" . join("|", $temp);
        else:
            $kv[] = "$k=$v";
        endif;
    }
    $post_vars = join("&", $kv);
}
```

This allows you to capture all the post data (regardless of its name or value) and then store than in a string, great for inserting into a database, though you might want to url encode it. I've updated it to include support for arrays but you'll have to customise it for your own requirements, it produces output  like this:

firstname=Terry&lastname=Kernan&userid=111111&device=999999999&text=Hello&questions=q1|q2|q3&answers=a1|a2|a3&type=manual

Comment: Another useful one I've been using is:
    serialize($_POST);
as it gives the entire object in a string, agaiun great for writing to a file or storing in the db

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

On your IPN page, you can log all get, post and cookie variables pretty easy.

Try this:

```
ob_start();
print_r($_REQUEST);
$data = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

file_put_contents("Path/to/log.file",$data);
```

Comment: simpler: file_put_contents( "path/to/log.file", print_r($_REQUEST, true));

Comment: how can i capture it into a variable? my app is already sending an email I could just add it to the email body.

Comment: @tacone, didn't know about that second parameter to print_r, thanks!

Comment: @saburius the output is in the `$data` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Post values are in the `$_POST` array.

Get values are in the `$_GET` array.

Get, post and cookie values are placed in `$_REQUEST`

Simply save and/or print the contents of those arrays as needed.

For more detailed info, check out:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php  
$req = 'What i reveive from paypal=====';          
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) // Loop through the key value pairs
    {         
        $req .= "\n\r$key=$value";                    // Add the key value pairs to the variable
    }
        mail('<Your own email address>','Data',$req,'from: <any email address of your own domain>');//mail yourself    
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `$_REQUEST` which is a combination of `$_GET` and `$_POST`.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php